# Difference between sub-sampling layer and convolutional layer (Convolution Neural Networks)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[image]

Can someone explain the difference between the **convolutional** and the **subsampling** layer?

Is it correct that in the convolutional step we **DEFINE** the convolutional filters with their weights, while in the subsampling step we **APPLY** the convolutional filter and determine their size by using strides and pooling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that convolution is an operation that is designed to extract features from the input, while sub-sampling's purpose is just to reduce the dimensions of the input. In standard CNNs, a convolution layer has trainable parameters which are tuned during the the training process, while the sub-sampling layer is a constant operation (usually performed by a max-pooling layer). In CNNs this max-pooling usually helps add some spatial invariance to the model.

I don't think that your last paragraph is the correct way of viewing it.

**Convolution:** You have a filter of a certain size. The output is the element wise multiplication of this filter and different areas (of similar size) of the input.
You can use the stride of the convolution filter to perform sub-sampling of the input.
For example:

[image]
[image]

For an input of 7x7, using a filter of the same size, in the first image with a stride of 1 pixel we get an output of 5x5, while using a stride of 2 pixels in the second image we get an output of 3x3. So technically we got sub-sampling as part of the convolution layer, but the sub-sampling is not trainable (the stride size is constant).

More often, when talking about a sub-sampling layer (and that is probably the case in the image you posted), the meaning is a max-pooling layer, which similarly to convolution, also has a filter and a stride of some size. However there are no-trainable weights (the output is just the max pixel of each area):

[image]

A rares case is using an average pooling layer for this sub-sampling layer.